# Is it possible to install a PWA precached with server's data?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Let me give you an example of the flow I am trying to achieve:

- A user enters the website
- The user has everything loaded (both files and network requests)
- Files are now cached due to `fetch` event listener
- The user installs the app on their phone (so far everything works as expected)
- All the data that has already been fetched by the user is transferred to the app so that the user could launch the app in offline mode.

Currently, the last step is not working. User must open the app at least once whilst online in order to make it work. Is it possible to "transfer" the website's cache to the app? If so, could you nudge me in the right direction with some helpful links? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#What_does_A2HS_not_give_you) will enlighten you

Comment: Tested right now on my computer (Chrome 80) the requests cached in the browser are used when the app is installed

Comment: @GuerricP does it work with mobile as well? Do you precache the data during the install event using `cache.addAll([])`?

Comment: @JaromandaX if I'm reading it correctly it just says that installing to your home screen does not save anything, implying this is possible, however, must be handled by service workers.

Comment: does your service worker do what is required?

Comment: @Fleeck indeed on Chrome under Android 9 it has a strange behavior, it adds a shortcut to the app instead of a plain icon, and it fails when starting

Comment: @JaromandaX it works offline, but only after I have launched the app at least once. I am trying to understand if it's possible to transfer the data from the website to the app during install.

Comment: regarding the *it adds a shortcut to the app instead of a plain icon* comment - PWA's install on Android with a little icon in the bottom right to indicate which browser to use to run the App ... try with Chrome, Firefox, Firefox Nightly ... you'll see the little chrome, firefox or firefox nightly icon overlayed on your icon - that's how PWA's *install* - the ramification of this is, if you install a PWA using firefox, then uninstall firefox, the PWA also disappears ... it's not a first class **App**

Comment: I'm pretty new to the world of PWA's - but - since a user decides to *install* a PWA, wouldn't the first thing you do after doing so is to launch the *App*? So, chances are, you'd still be online in the seconds after *install*?

Comment: @JaromandaX you're totally right. However, this is what I've been asked to check out. Install the app, go offline and forget about fetching stuff whatsoever.

Comment: @JaromandaX still the behavior is different when online, the icon in the bottom right doesn't show

Comment: @GuerricP - wha? it sure does on android 9 and 10 firefox and chrome - are you referring to some desktop environment?

Comment: @JaromandaX it actually works well with Safari iPhone. But Android and Chrome do not. Maybe I will check the Chrome docs or something like that